# ¿Blazor tiene alga funcionalidad como el $attrs de Vue?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

El $attrs en vue es algo realmente útil en el diseño de componentes. Si tengo un componente que genera una etiqueta `a`, podría usar `$attrs` para pasarle todas sus propiedades nativas sin necesidad de crear un parámetro para cada uno de ellos..

Por ejemplo, teniendo el siguiente componente..

```
<div>
    <a href="@Href" onclick="@OnClick" class="@Classes" style="@Styles">@Content</a>
</div>
```

Esto me obliga a declarar los parámetros `Href`, `OnClick`, `Classes`, `Styles`, pero sabemos que la etiqueta `a` tiene una gran cantidad de parámetros, como `target`, `hreflang`, etc y ni hablar de otros elementos como podría ser un `input`.

Habiendo mostrado este ejemplo..

¿Blazor tiene alguna funcionalidad similar?

[Pregunta en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57426621/5213794)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

¡Si, la tiene!

Para esto, puede usarse el nuevo [operador splat](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-ES/aspnet/core/blazor/components?view=aspnetcore-3.0#attribute-splatting-and-arbitrary-parameters), por ejemplo

```
// MyComp

<div id="@Id" @attributes="InputAttributes"></div>

@code {
    [Parameter] string Id { get; set; } 
    [Parameter(CaptureUnmatchedValues = true)]
    private Dictionary<string, object> InputAttributes { get; set; }
}
```

La definición de un parámetro como el del ejemplo anterior, producirá que se apliquen todos los parámetros definidos en el componente que no coincidan con otro parámetro existente.

Uso:

```
<MyComp Id="foo" class="myclass" />
```

Debería renderizar

```
<div id="foo" class="myclass"></div>
```

[Respuesta en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57426806/5213794)